# Acceder a atributo de etiqueta xml usando DOM para posteriormente mostrar en html

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

estoy tratando de acceder a una información en unn documento xml, y mostrarla en forma de tabla en html usando javascript.
me falta unicamente mostrar una información que se encuentra como atributo de una de las etiquetas del xml. El atributo es convocatoria. Este es el xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<alumnos> 
    <alumno> 
        <nombre>Maria</nombre> 
        <apellido>Campos</apellido> 
        <nota convocatoria="EVA1">8.3</nota> 
    </alumno> 
    <alumno> 
        <nombre>Jose</nombre> 
        <apellido>Garcia</apellido> 
        <nota convocatoria=" EVA1">6.7</nota> 
    </alumno> 
    <alumno> 
        <nombre>Marcos</nombre> 
        <apellido>Galvez</apellido> 
        <nota convocatoria=" EVA1">3.5</nota> 
    </alumno> 
</alumnos>
```

Deseo que rellene la tabla de la siguiente manera:

[image: resultado deseado]

Estoy usando getAttribute() ya que no es un atributo estandarizado pero no recibo nada, he probado varias maneras pero no se exactamente cómo llegar a él para mostrarlo.
Os dejo el código entero.

```
<body>

    <br><br>
    <table id="alumnos"></table>
    <script>

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                myFunction(this);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "alumnos.xml", true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        function myFunction(xml) {
            var i;
            var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
            var table = "<tr><th>Nombre</th><th>Apellido</th><th>Nota</th><th>Convocatoria</th></tr>";
            var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("alumno");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                table += "<tr><td>" +
                    x[i].getElementsByTagName("nombre")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    x[i].getElementsByTagName("apellido")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    x[i].getElementsByTagName("nota")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                    //"</td><td>" +
                    //x[i].getElementsByTagName("nota")[0].childNodes[0].getAttribute('convocatoria') +
                    "</td></tr>";
            }
            document.getElementById("alumnos").innerHTML = table;
            
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

La parte donde trato de acceder al atributo es la comentada abajo del todo.
Ayuda!...

Comment: Hay un error de tipeo o dice `documen.getAttribute("convocatoria");` debería decir `document.getAttribute("convocatoria");` con la t de document

Comment: perdón, ignora esa línea, era solo para ver si accedía al atributo fuera de la función de manera simple. Lo que trato de hacer que funcione es lo que está comentado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El childNode te puede ser útil para obtener el valor interno, pero el método `getAttribute` pertenece a los elementos obtenido del xml.

```
<body>

    <br><br>
    <table id="alumnos"></table>
    <script>

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                myFunction(this);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "alumnos.xml", true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        function myFunction(xml) {
            var i;
            var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
            var table = "<tr><th>Nombre</th><th>Apellido</th><th>Nota</th><th>Convocatoria</th></tr>";
            var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("alumno");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                table += "<tr><td>" +
                    x[i].getElementsByTagName("nombre")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    x[i].getElementsByTagName("apellido")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    x[i].getElementsByTagName("nota")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    x[i].getElementsByTagName("nota")[0].getAttribute('convocatoria') +
                    "</td></tr>";
            }
            document.getElementById("alumnos").innerHTML = table;
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: y tan simple como eso... juraría que lo había probado ya... gracias por sacarme del efecto tunel!!

Comment: Coincido plenamente que a veces nos estancamos y un par de ojos extras ven el elefante que estamos ignorando. Fue muy fácil ayudarte porque pusiste código reproducible y completo.